# Does calling glBufferData create/release buffers?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm working on a program that loads new data of a model to the graphics card using OpenGL, it then switches to rendering that one, and then removes the old data so as to create more space for other uses.

From my understanding I shouldn't be creating/releasing buffers on the fly as it can lead to memory thrashing.

Is it bad to call glBufferData frequently to add new data to the graphics card? Does this count as creating/releasing buffers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `glBufferData` with the same size and usage parameters as it was called previously, then this is effectively invalidating or "orphaning" the buffer. To do anything else, to change the size or usage, is to effectively create a new buffer.

If you aren't streaming data (uploading new data every frame or so), invalidation is not especially useful. If you're no longer using the buffer, and you haven't used it in a while, just leave it there if you're going to need buffer storage again.

And if your models use different sizes, preallocate a large buffer object and have different models use different regions from that one allocation.

Comment: If you've already allocated a buffer with glBufferData and need to update/replace the data, you can use [glBufferSubData](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBufferSubData.xml) to change the data while ensuring that no new allocations are made.

Comment: Using glBufferSubData data updates may be partial and thus require the creation of a shadow copy.  When orphaning is carried out that copying step can be skipped.

Comment: I can't get glBufferSubData to work properly. I call this code on initialisation to create the initial buffers:

`glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
 glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, space * sizeof(float), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);`

When the vertex data is set, I use the following line:

`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, count * sizeof(float), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);`

however swapping it out for

`glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL, count * sizeof(float), (const GLvoid*)vertices);`

causes the model to no longer render. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It appears (as one would expect) that it was an issue on my end. It appears to not work when I map a pointer to the buffer beforehand - removing this mapping fixed the problem.